# How to get divisors of any number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print out divisors of an entered number and not getting the desirable results. I think the code I've written is correct but the outcome isn't really what I'm expecting. Please help me point out my mistakes, if any

```
def divisors():
    a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    x = list(range(2, a+1))

    for item in x:
        if a % item == 0:
            print(item)
        else:
            break
    divisors()
```

Comment: Remove everything down from else, no need to break and no need to recursively call itself.

Comment: You should always give an example input and output for your questions where possible

Comment: Thank you so much guys! removing break solves the problem and I will remember to put the output next time!

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `break`, it makes your loop to stop the first time you encounter a non-divisor:

```
def divisors():
    a = int(input("Enter a number: "))
    x = list(range(2, a+1))

    for item in x:
        if a % item == 0:
            print(item)
```